# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar module.exports y exports en node.js?

Tags: nodejs, express, modulos, exports, module.exports

tengo esta duda, ya que a pesar de que leído y buscado información aún no me queda totalmente claro. Según lo poco que entendí hasta ahora es que exports es como una propieda de module, vi que si uno hace un console.log(module) exports es una propiedad de este, pero sinceramente no entiendo en que casos usar una forma y la otra. Toda esta duda me surgió con el siguiente problema. Tengo un manejador de rutas en node.js así:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const router = express.Router();
const Users = require('../models/users.js');
const middlewareCheckToken = require('./middleware.js').checkToken;
const server = require('../server.js');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt'); // para encryptar la contraseña
const moment = require('moment'); // librería para crear fechas
const jwt = require('jwt-simple'); // librería para crear token


// router.use(function timeLog(req, res,next) {
//   console.log('Funcion de la rutaaaaaa');
//   next();
// });



const createToken = (user) => { //Función para crear el Token del usuario
 let payload = {
  userId: user.id_usuario,
  createdAt: moment().unix(),
  expiresAt: moment().add(1,'day').unix()
 }
 return {token: jwt.encode(payload, process.env.TOKEN_KEY),
  expires_in: payload.expiresAt
 };
}



router.get('/hola', async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const users = await Users.getAll();
  res.send(users);

 }catch(e){
  res.send('Ocurrio un error: '+e);
 }

});


router.post('/signin', async (req, res) => {
 // console.log('Entró a la petición SIGNIN.');
 // console.log('Cuerpo de la petición:', req.body);
 //req.body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
 // console.log('--------------------');
 console.log('contrasena:'+req.body.pass)
 const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(); 
 req.body.pass = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.pass,salt);
 console.log('PASS ENCRIPTADA:'+req.body.pass);

 try{
  const result = await Users.registerUser(req.body);
  const lastUserInserted = await Users.getLastIdInserted(); 
  //console.log('Ultimo user inserteado:',lastUserInserted[0]);
  //console.log('id',lastUserInserted[0])
  // console.log('Resultado final: ',result);
  const infoToken = createToken(lastUserInserted[0]);
  res.status(200).json({
   user: {  
    name: lastUserInserted[0].nombres,
    lastName: lastUserInserted[0].apellidos,
    email: lastUserInserted[0].correo,
    access_token: infoToken.token,
    expires_in: infoToken.expires_in

   }
  });
 }catch(error){
  res.send('Ocurrió un Error al Insertar Usuario '+error);
  console.log('Ocurrió un Error al Insertar Usuario '+error);
 }
});


router.post('/entry', async (req, res) => {
 try{
  console.log('Clave --->'+req.body.pass);
  const infoUser = await Users.getByEmail(req.body.email);
  if( infoUser == 0){
   res.status(200).json({
    error: 'Error, el correo no se encuentra registrado',
    email: 'correo incorrect'
   });
  }else{
   console.log('Hash ---->'+infoUser[0].clave)
   console.log('Clave --->'+req.body.pass);
   const equals = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.pass, infoUser[0].clave);
   console.log('equals: '+equals)
   if(!equals){
    res.status(200).json({
     error: 'Error, clave incorrecta',
     pass: 'pass incorrect'
    });
   }else{
    const infoToken = createToken(infoUser[0]);
    res.status(200).json({
     user: {  
      name: infoUser[0].nombres,
      lastName: infoUser[0].apellidos,
      email: infoUser[0].correo,
      access_token: infoToken.token,
      expires_in: infoToken.expires_in
     }
    }); 
   }
  }
 }catch(error){
  res.send('Ocurrió un Error verificando el email:   '+error.message);
  console.log('Ocurrió un Error verificando el email:   '+error.message);
 }





 // console.log('Entró a la petición.');
 // console.log('Parámetros: ',req.body);
 // //req.body.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
 // try{
 //  const result = await Users.insert(req.body);
 //  res.json(result)
 // }catch(e){
 //  res.send('Ocurrió un Error al Insertar Usuario'+e);
 //  console.log('Ocurrió un Error al Insertar Usuario'+e);
 // }
});

router.use(middlewareCheckToken);

router.get('/getUser', (req, res) => {
 Users.getById(req.query.userId)
  .then( rows => {
   res.json(rows);
  } )
  .catch( err => console.log(err) );
})


// router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
//  try {
//   const users = await Users.getAll();
//   res.send(users);

//  }catch(e){
//   res.send('Ocurrio un error: '+e);
//  }

// });

module.exports = router
```

Necesitaba usar la función createToken en un modelo para crear el token y guardarlo en la base de datos, así que quería exportar esa función, intenté hacer esto:  `module.exports = { router, createToken: createToken}` pero me muestra este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras que cuándo lo coloco así: `module.exports = router; 
exports = { createToken: createToken};`NO me muestra ningún error, así que por eso tengo la duda. En una página si vi que existe una leve diferencia, pero sinceramente no la entendí. Si alguien pudiera aclarármela de la forma mas simple posible estaría enormemente agradecido. Gracias de antemano. Saludos!

Comment: que error te muestra?

Comment: Hola @RimuruTempest , acabo de editar mi pregunta mostrando una captura del error.

Comment: Ahí claramente te dice que la función `Router.use()` necesita un middleware osea una función no un objeto

Comment: Pero ese error solamente aparece cuando colocó el module.exports de la forma que mostré, si lo modifico desaparece.